# SocketIO App behaving strangely on Heroku but working locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have logs in server and in client apps.

A component emits a SocketIO event when clicked. Now the first client (first window opened to page) clicks the component and I see the logs on the server that an event was received and on client that a event was sent.

Now the funny thing is, when I duplicate the tab, the server registers a new user (socket connection successful) but when I click the components, then there is no message saying the event was sent but the component does change color.

I am sending the SocketIO event and console.logging the message in the callback of setState.

The component in question is a cell.

This is my code:

```
handleOnCellClick() {
    if (!this.state.alive) {
      // if dead then proceed add some color to the Cell's life :) and notify server of event
      console.log("cell wasn't alive");
      this.setState(
        {
          r: this.props.defaultRandomColorProps[0],
          g: this.props.defaultRandomColorProps[1],
          b: this.props.defaultRandomColorProps[2],
          alive: true
        },
        () => {
          this.props.socketProps.emit("cellChanged", {
            key: [this.props.cell_row_index, this.props.cell_col_index],
            color: { r: this.state.r, g: this.state.g, b: this.state.b }
          });
          console.log("emitted");
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

In fact, please see this for yourself at [secret-forest-30430.herokuapp.com/](http://secret-forest-30430.herokuapp.com/) . Navigate over to the Game tab. It contains a "board" of Cell components.

Again I must reiterate, that this whole thing works locally. Here's the link for the project on github: https://github.com/Dobermensch/ExpressTest.git

Any idea what's going on?

**TL;DR**: setState callback not working?

**EDIT**: for a stepback, I am trying to create a multiplayer [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life)

Comment: I am running your app on 2 different tabs and getting the emitted message and event received from other cell change message in the console.

Comment: really? then what's going on on my end?

Comment: Are you using Chome? I'm using FireFox

Comment: Yes I am using chrome. @ayudh

Comment: Thanks, I'll try with Chome. Give me a second as I'll have to download it...

Comment: Which package are you using for web socket? Did you check its documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201011/discussion-between-ayudh-and-vaibhav-singh).

Comment: Just tried Chrome and it's bloody working... Thank you Mr. Singh. Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct if you'd like

Comment: No Problem :) Sorry could not join your chat as I am over VPN :(

Comment: Add it as an answer bro, common.